# extracting unique rows of data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to extract only the rows when `b` is unique value per `a`.

Here is some sample data

```
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10)
b <- c(1,2,1,1,5,5,6,1,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,2)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
```

and using the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

Unique <- df1 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(b))
```

The desired output should be a data frame length 18

Comment: does it have to be with dplyr? `unique(df1)` already does that and is a lot faster

Answer (score 5):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    distinct()
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
unique(df1)
```

Comment: @mtoto Thanks, but I think the OP want to include `%>%`